# Python: possible to call static method from within class without qualifying the name

Tags: python, class, namespaces

This is annoying:

```
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        print "hi"

    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        MyClass.foo()
```

Is there a way to make this work without naming MyClass in the call?  i.e. so I can just say `foo()` on the last line?

Comment: Nope. What are you trying to achive?

Comment: A class method takes the class as the first parameter _because it uses the class_. `bar` should be a `@classmethod`.

Comment: If the class is entirely static methods, maybe it could be refactored to a module with top-level functions that represent its public API. Then there is no prefixing to deal with, yet the functions are still grouped as a logical entity. Example: [cpython/Lib/copy.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/de33df27aaf930be6a34027c530a651f0b4c91f5/Lib/copy.py). Note that private functions on the module are prefixed with `_` as normal.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no way to use `foo` and get what you want.  There is no implicit class scope, so `foo` is either a local or a global, neither of which you want.

You might find classmethods more useful:

```
class MyClass:
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        print "hi"

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        cls.foo()
```

This way, at least you don't have to repeat the name of the class.

Comment: Why make `foo` a `classmethod` when you're not using the class?  I'd make `foo` a `staticmethod` and `bar` a `classmethod` (as you've done).

Answer (score 2):

Not possible. It is a question of language design. Compare that to C++, where both `this` (the same as Python `self`; in Python you have to write `self.var`, in C++ you may write just `var`, not `this->var`) and own class are used by default in member functions, and you will probably see that sometimes that's good and sometimes that's annoying. The only thing possible is to get used to that feature.

Answer (score 0):

You 'variable-ize' the class name. This will not remove, but shorten the name.

```
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        print "hi"

    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        c.foo()

c = MyClass
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something hacky by making a module level function `foo` and then adding it to the class namespace with `staticmethod`:

```
def foo():
    print "hi"

class MyClass(object):
    foo = staticmethod(foo)

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        return cls.foo()

    def baz(self):
        return foo()


c = MyClass()
c.bar()
c.baz()

MyClass.bar()
MyClass.foo()
```