# Multiprocessing apply_async() not working on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, asynchronous, multiprocessing, cherrypy

I am running this code as a CherryPy Web Service both on Mac OS X and Ubuntu 14.04. By using `multiprocessing` on python3 I want to start the static method `worker()` in an asynchronous way, within a `Process Pool`.

The same code runs flawlessly on Mac OS X, in Ubuntu 14.04 `worker()` does not run. I.e. by debugging the code inside the `POST` method I am able to see that each line is executed - from

```
reqid = str(uuid.uuid4())
```

to

```
return handle_error(202, "Request ID: " + reqid)
```

Starting the same code in Ubuntu 14.04, it does not run the `worker()` method, not even a `print()` at the top of the method (which would be logged).

Here's the relevant code (I only omitted the `handle_error()` method):

```
import cherrypy
import json
from lib import get_parameters, handle_error
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
from pymatbridge import Matlab
import requests
import shutil
import uuid
from xml.etree import ElementTree

class Schedule(object):
    exposed = True

    def __init__(self, mlab_path, pool):
        self.mlab_path = mlab_path
        self.pool = pool

    def POST(self, *paths, **params):

        if validate(cherrypy.request.headers):

            try:
                reqid = str(uuid.uuid4())
                path = os.path.join("results", reqid)
                os.makedirs(path)
                wargs = [(self.mlab_path, reqid)]
                self.pool.apply_async(Schedule.worker, wargs)

                return handle_error(202, "Request ID: " + reqid)
            except:
                return handle_error(500, "Internal Server Error")
        else:
            return handle_error(401, "Unauthorized")

    #### this is not executed ####
    @staticmethod
    def worker(args):

        mlab_path, reqid = args
        mlab = Matlab(executable=mlab_path)
        mlab.start()

        mlab.run_code("cd mlab")
        mlab.run_code("sched")
        a = mlab.get_variable("a")

        mlab.stop()

        return reqid

    ####

# to start the Web Service
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # start Web Service with some configuration
    global_conf = {
           "global":    {
                            "server.environment": "production",
                            "engine.autoreload.on": True,
                            "engine.autoreload.frequency": 5,
                            "server.socket_host": "0.0.0.0",
                            "log.screen": False,
                            "log.access_file": "site.log",
                            "log.error_file": "site.log",
                            "server.socket_port": 8084
                        }
    }
    cherrypy.config.update(global_conf)
    conf = {
        "/": {
            "request.dispatch": cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
            "tools.encode.debug": True,
            "request.show_tracebacks": False
        }
    }

    pool = Pool(3)

    cherrypy.tree.mount(Schedule('matlab', pool), "/sched", conf)

    # activate signal handler
    if hasattr(cherrypy.engine, "signal_handler"):
        cherrypy.engine.signal_handler.subscribe()

    # start serving pages
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```

Comment: You could try to provide a minimal reproducible example, that will definitely help. Also, "does not run" is a bit ambiguous... do you get an error? can you post it?

Comment: Hi @Peque, I got no error. I tried to debug the code but it seems not to be executed - I just started with some basic `print()` statement, outside the method the output is shown. I provided a minimal reproducible example. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your logic is hiding the problem from you. The `apply_async` method returns an [AsyncResult](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) object which acts as a handler to the asynchronous task you just scheduled. As you ignore the outcome of the scheduled task, the whole thing looks like "failing silently".

If you try to get the results from that task, you'd see the real problem.

```
handler = self.pool.apply_async(Schedule.worker, wargs)
handler.get()

... traceback here ...
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

In short, you must ensure the arguments you pass to the Pool are [Picklable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled).

Instance and class methods are Picklable if the object/class they belong to is picklable as well. Static methods are not picklable because they loose the association with the object itself, therefore the pickle library cannot serialise them correctly.

As a general line, is better to avoid scheduling to `multiprocessing.Pool` anything different than a top level defined functions.

Comment: This did not fixed my problem, but led me to the original error of the asynced function. [My error afterwards was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56804933/python-multiprocessing-process-pool-fails-to-find-asynced-function-in-same-file), that it could not find the function to be asynced

Answer (score 2):

To run a background tasks with Cherrypy it's better if you use an asynchronous task queue manager like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) or [RQ](http://python-rq.org/). This services are very easy to install and run, your tasks will run in a completely separated process and if you need to scale because your load is increasing it'll be very straight forward.

You have a simple example with Cherrypy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644974/how-to-return-data-from-a-cherrypy-backgroundtask-running-as-fast-as-possible/36750783#36750783).

Answer (score 0):

I solved changing the method from `@staticmethod` to `@classmethod`. Now the job runs inside the `ProcessPool`. I found classmethods to be more useful in this case, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340679/python-possible-to-call-static-method-from-within-class-without-qualifying-the).

Thanks.

Comment: In this case it is important that it is bundled in the class, because each class in cherrypy represent a Web Service. In my case, each Web Service has a different worker thread to execute, so it is better IMHO to have it bundled in the corresponding class. However, if there is a better design practice please tell me :)

Comment: I think that the overhead of declaring `worker` as a `classmethod` is negligible in this case, and the `worker` is related to the class enough to be a class member. The name `worker` is due to the fact that the class already has a descriptive name for what the Web Service is going to do, the `worker` just work on that. What are the advantages of using a static method?