# python multiprocessing process pool fails to find asynced function

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Pretty simple multiprocessing example. Goals:

1. Create a pool of process workers using `mp.Pool`
2. Do some sort of transformation (here a simple string operation on `line`)
3. Push the transformed line to `mp.Queue`
4. Further process data from that `mp.Queue` in the main program afterwards

So lets do this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
```

Init async processes with a mp.queue

```
def process_pool_init_per_process(q):
    global mp_queue
    mp_queue = q
```

Really init the mp_pool

```
no_of_processes = 4
q = mp.Queue()
mp_pool = mp.Pool(no_of_processes, process_pool_init_per_process, (q,))
```

This is getting called for every `line` to be proccesed async

```
def process_async_main(line):
    print(line)
    q.put(line + '_asynced')
```

And now let´s start it using `apply_async`

```
line = "Hi, this is a test to test mp_queues with mp process pools"
handler = mp_pool.apply_async(process_async_main, (line))
mp_resp = handler.get()
```

And read from the queue

```
while not q.empty():
    print(q.get()) # This should be the inital line
```

Fails wih:

```
python3 mp_process_example.py
Process ForkPoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 337, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'process_async_main' on <module '__main__' from 'mp_process_example.py'>
```

The question is: **Why is multiprocessing not finding the main class?**

Complete code to reproduce:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

##### Init async processes
def process_pool_init_per_process(q):
    global mp_queue
    mp_queue = q

# Really init the mp_pool
no_of_processes = 4
q = mp.Queue()
mp_pool = mp.Pool(no_of_processes, process_pool_init_per_process, (q,))

#This is getting called for every line to be proccesed async
def process_async_main(line):
    print(line)
    q.put(line + '_asynced')

line = "Hi, this is a test to test mp_queues with mp process pools"
handler = mp_pool.apply_async(process_async_main, (line))
mp_resp = handler.get()

while not q.empty():
    print(q.get()) # This should be the inital line
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok... I´ve got it... For some strange reason **`multiprocessing` is not able to have the function to be asynced in the same file as the synchronized code**.

Writing the code like this:

`asynced.py`

```
##### Init async processes
def process_pool_init_per_process(q):
    global mp_queue
    mp_queue = q

##### Function to be asycned
def process_async_main(line):
    print(line)
    mp_queue.put(line + '_asynced')
```

And than `mp_process_example.py`:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from asynced import process_async_main, process_pool_init_per_process


# Really init the mp_pool
no_of_processes = 4
q = mp.Queue()
mp_pool = mp.Pool(no_of_processes, process_pool_init_per_process, (q,))

line = "Hi, this is a test to test mp_queues with mp process pools"
handler = mp_pool.apply_async(process_async_main, (line,))
mp_resp = handler.get()

while not q.empty():
    print(q.get()) # This should be the inital line + "_asynced"
```

Works as expected:

```
$ python3 mp_process_example.py
Hi, this is a test to test mp_queues with mp process pools
Hi, this is a test to test mp_queues with mp process pools_asynced
```

Comment: It's not a matter of "the same file". I think it's a matter of "function should be defined before pool is created". The reason is that in `apply_async` you actually don't pass a function (how would you pass a function between processes?) but rather its identifier which is then imported in the child process. And if you create the pool before definition then the child doesn't have it. And so you get the error. Move `process_async_main` before pool creation to see the effect.

Comment: This is my guess though. Some diving into CPython internals is needed to confirm that.

Comment: Also another hint: multiprocessing doesn't seem to work correctly when initialized before the module is fully imported (your case). I advice using some lazy evaluation, i.e. you wrap everything in `def run()` function, you import the module and call `run()`.

Comment: @freakish: I just tried it out - **You are correct!** I was not expecting that behaviour because the `process_async_main` function is not getting pushed into the init of the asynced processes but called latr during `apply_async`. But as you say.. It needs to be present before the init of the `mp.Pool`.. Thank you very much!