# Writing a unit test for a method in a class that calls a static method

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have the following static method in my Class:

```
@staticmethod
def get_previous_month(date):
    previous_month = date - relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
    return previous_month
```

Below it, i'm using it in a class method.

```
def transform_last_price(self, data):

    full_data = data. \
        addfield('TimeSeriesValue'). \
        convert('EffectiveDate', lambda x: date_converter(x)) 

    # Break table to dict_data... Does other stuff...

    # Calls static method:
    base_month = get_previous_month(dict_data[0]['EffectiveDate'])

    # Do more stuff...

    # Transform mapped dict into table
    lastPriceData = etl. \
        fromdicts(dict_data). \
        addfield('FundID', self.FUND_ID). \
        addfield('TimeSeriesTypeID', 12). \
        cutout('MTDReturn')

    return lastPriceData
```

I'm trying to write a unit test that checks that if some dates were converted into date objects.

```
def test_convert_date_strings_to_date_objects(self):
    data = etl.fromdicts([{'EffectiveDate': '1990-08-31'}])
    transformed_dates = self.parser.transform_last_price(data)
    date = transformed_dates.values('EffectiveDate')[0]
    self.assertIsInstance(date, datetime.date)
```

However, i'm getting the following error:

`NameError: name 'get_previous_month' is not defined`

I'm assuming that the test does not have access to the static method? I'm not sure how to re-write this. I already wrote a test for `get_previous_month` separately and it's working but i'm writing more of an integration test for `transform_last_price`

Comment: Are all of the code snippets in the same file? If not, please show the file structure and import statements.

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket where you call `get_previous_month` also you cannot call `get_previous_month` like you do. See here on how you can call static functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340679/python-possible-to-call-static-method-from-within-class-without-qualifying-the. Basically you need to do `MyClass.get_previous_month...`

Comment: `self.get_previous_month` you need to put `self` because it is also class method, if you put `staticmethod` decorator that doesn't mean that you don't need to use `self`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

static methods should be called with syntax: self.methodName() or Class.methodName(). you simply use methodName which won't work. (Python would try to resolve it against the global namespace)

Comment: Thank you, I just added `self` and it's working. I have to write a dummy data set that's able to go through the whole method of `transform_last_price` though, annoying but I don't think I have another choice for that.